# In R - Extracting a value from a column, by the rule of finding the highest value of a different value

Tags: r, max

i have a `3 x 8` Data Frame, and i need to extract the day (column 3) that matches the highest value (column 1) from the Data Frame.

For example,

```
1    0.931 2015-03-20    Friday
2   -0.105 2015-03-23    Monday
3   -0.470 2015-03-24   Tuesday
4   -0.149 2015-03-25 Wednesday
```

the highest value is 0.931, so i need to extract the value Friday.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `df[which.max(df$value), 3]`

Comment: response is character (0), column #3 isnt defined as vector. it was created through a command that create a column that indicates the day of a certain date.                                                            DF_sec5$TrdDate_Weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(DF_sec5$TrdDate)) , for this df > DF_sec5
  VWRet_DF TrdDate_DF        NA
1    0.931 2015-03-20    Friday
2   -0.105 2015-03-23    Monday
3   -0.470 2015-03-24   Tuesday
4   -0.149 2015-03-25 Wednesday
5   -0.218 2015-03-26  Thursday
6    0.250 2015-03-27    Friday
7    1.171 2015-03-30    Monday
8   -7.162 2015-03-31   Tuesday

Comment: Posting your data helps others help you. For example, if your data frame is named `df`, you can give us your data by posting the output of `dput(df)` in your question. Read more about creating a minimal reproducible example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Say, your dataframe (`df`) has the values in column named `V1` then you can find the index of the maximum value in this column with `which.max(df$V1)`. You say you want the corresponding day for this value, say the days are in column named `V2` then your day is `df$V2[which.max(df$V1)]`.